# Using both "AND" and "OR" in a scope in Sequelize js

Tags: javascript, express, orm, sequelize.js

Encountering more trouble with the lovely Sequelize JS.

I'm trying to put the following query into a Sequelize scope.

```
SELECT *
FROM Projects
WHERE isDeleted IS NOT true
AND ( 
    ( importSource IS NOT null ) AND ( createdAt BETWEEN '2018-01-19' AND '2018-01-29') 
    OR 
    ( importSource IS null ) AND ( createdAt > '2018-01-19' )
)
```

Trying this at the moment to no avail in my model.

```
scopes: {
  active: {
    where: {
      isDeleted: {
        [Op.not]: true
      },
      [Op.or]: [
        {
          importSource: { [Op.ne]: null },
          createdAt: {
            [Op.between]: [
              new Date(new Date() - 30 * ( 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)),
              new Date(new Date() - 4 * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
            ],
          }
        },
        {
          importSource: { [Op.eq]: null },
          createdAt: {
            [Op.gt]: new Date(new Date() - 30 * ( 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)),
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

There is no error. Just this the following MySQL that's being run.

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `url`, `title`, `company`, `importSource`, `importSourceId`, `publishedAt`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Projects` AS `Project` WHERE `Project`.`isDeleted` IS NOT true ORDER BY `Project`.`id` DESC LIMIT 5;
```

And here is the controller method calling the model and scope.

```
exports.index = (req, res) => {
  const MAX = 50;
  var numberProjects = ((req.query.number) ? req.query.number : MAX);
  numberProjects = ((numberProjects > MAX) ? MAX : numberProjects);

  Project.scope('active').findAll({
    order: [
      ['id', 'DESC']
    ],
    limit: +numberProjects
  })
  .then( projects => {
    res.send( projects );
  })
};
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve this 20 minutes after asking this.

Changed the `[Op.or]` to `$or` seemed to work.

```
scopes: {
  active: {
    where: {
      isDeleted: { [Op.not]: true },
      $or: [
        {
          importSource: { [Op.ne]: null },
          createdAt: {
            [Op.between]: [
              new Date(new Date() - 30 * ( 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)),
              new Date(new Date() - 4 * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
            ],
          }
        },
        {
          importSource: { [Op.eq]: null },
          createdAt: {
            [Op.gt]: new Date(new Date() - 30 * ( 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)),
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow - i had the same issue, and changing the top level to $or worked for me too. Do you know why this is?